EF Core view - placement of business logic
A question about EF Core as I can't see how to do this scenario cleanly. This isn't my actual scenario but a simplified example.
Let's say I have a class Person which has many Meals.
In the entity class Person, there is a property LastMealDateTime which returns the date of last meal that person ate via a Linq query.  This works great at the business layer level and is just what I want.
Say though, I want to list all the Person records with the last meal they ate (maybe an export to file or a grid...).
I could load all the Person records and grab the LastMealDateTime property but that will result in N... calls to the database, and if there are thousands of Person records, then that results in thousands of extra calls.
A solution to the performance issue would be to create a view in the database and bind directly to that.
Imagine:
SELECT
    PersonName, 
    (SELECT TOP 1 MealDateTime 
     FROM Meal 
     WHERE Meal.PersonId = Person.Id)
FROM 
    Person .....

This is great, nice and efficient as we are leaving it to the database engine to do all the join work etc.
But, this view is now containing some business logic (getting the last meal a person ate), which duplicates the property LastMealDateTime in the Person class. I don't want to have to have multiple places where we execute this logic.
This is a very simple example with some very simple business logic and to be honest I'd probably let something like this go but if the logic was a lot more complicated we'd be duplicating it.
What neat solutions have people come up with to get round this?

EF Core can do JOINs just fine ... what makes you think it can't or won't? => https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/complex-query-operators#join

This isn't my actual scenario but a simplified example - the danger with doing that is not being able to translate the advice received back to your complex situation. Caveat emptor

A solution to - what you have posted is not a solution. Your TOP query lacks an order by and is hence meaningless.  Consider a window function based approach. EF can actually do it for you (it can translate a particularly crafted linq to eg a ROW_NUMBER OVER to pull just the latest meal)

You can achieve this without using a view by utilizing EF Core as follows:
Using Include to return only the last meal:
var query = ctx.Person
    .Include(p => p.Meals.OrderByDescending(m => m.MealDateTime).Take(1));

Or with Select:
var query = ctx.Person
    .Select(p => new PersonDto
    {
        Id = p.Id,
        LastMeal = p.Meals.OrderByDescending(m => m.MealDateTime).FirstOrDefault()
    });


Ahh of course, why didn't I think of that.  Thanks very much!

Or even the whole Person like Select(p => new { Person = p, LastMeal = ....

Thanks, my EF is rusty as haven't used it for a long time.  Just getting back into it!
